# How to trigger click after a short delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, pug

I am building a Backbone App, my view is like this

```
define(function (require) {

    'use strict';

    var MyBackbone      = require('mybackbone'),
        template        = require('utils/template'),
        Handlebars      = require('handlebars'),
        Contest          = require('controllers/ads/contest');

    var Main = MyBackbone.View.extend({

        initialize : function( options ) {
            MyBackbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
            this.template = Handlebars.compile( template.get( "presentation/page/main" ) );
            this.loadChildViews( "footer", new Contest() );
        },

        render: function(){
            var renderedContent = this.template();
            this.$el.html( renderedContent );
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            "click .show-message": "hideAndShowMessage"
        },

        hideAndShowMessage: function(e){
            var self = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.find('.is-hidding:visible').addClass('hideFade');
            this.$el.find('.bg-lets-go').removeClass('hideFade');
            var targetLink = $(e.currentTarget);
            targetLink.removeClass('show-message');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('a.no-style:not(".show-message")', self.$el).trigger("click");
                //$('a.no-style:not(".show-message")').click();
                //targetLink.trigger('click');
            }, 750);
        }
    });

    return Main;
});
```

and my main.jade

```
div.main-container
    .container-fluid.is-hidding
        .row
            .col-xs-6
                a.no-style.btn-ipurpose.show-message(href="/#ipurpose")
                    i.fa.fa-tree.fa-3x
                    | JE PROPOSE

            .col-xs-6
                a.no-style.btn-ichoose.show-message(href="/#ichoose")
                    i.fa.fa-flag-checkered.fa-3x
                    | JE CHOISIS

.bg.bg-lets-go.is-hidding.hideFade
.bg.bg-simple
```

the goal is to display a "let's go message" for 750ms after the link is clicked.

I have tried few stuff into the setTimeout but none of them work.
No javascript error, is it the right way to do so ?

Comment: To show an element, then hide it after 750ms, you can do something like: `$('.bg-lets-go').show("slow").delay(750).hide("slow");`. Sorry I can't give a full answer as I'm unfamiliar with Jade and Backbone.js.

Comment: How do you know the click doesn't do anything? What cares about those fragments? The basic structure seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mb85yc2r/, what are you doing differently?

Comment: Why don't you just use toastr http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/
it has a built in timeout also.

Comment: @DaveSalomon, I am using css3 transition on opacity, this is not the behaviour i am looking for

Comment: @muistooshort The router isn't triggered, on javascript link call, I can't see a difference, how did you make it work ?

Comment: @ZeeTee I don't need an extra library for doing that :/

Comment: Modify my fiddle to match what you're doing (probably a router instead of my extra click handler) and replicate the behavior you're seeing. That process will either show you where you're going wrong or give us a fighting chance to see what's wrong.

Comment: @muistooshort I have updated the jsfiddle (previous wasn't correct) 
http://jsfiddle.net/mb85yc2r/7/   with this logic, the router pancakes method should be called

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are making a mistake in your logic.

You are again sending the click event to the same anchor which was clicked before. A listener will still be bound to this element, resulting in hideAndShowMessage to be called again. In that method you call e.preventDefault() again. You start the timeout after which the click is send and we start all over again; basically an infinite loop.

A quick-fix for your issue would be to make the preventDefault call conditional:

```
var targetLink = $(e.currentTarget);
if(targetLink.hasClass(".show-message")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //....rest of your logic
}
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: unfortunatly, it didnt, see http://jsfiddle.net/mb85yc2r/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mb85yc2r/7/ for details. I am actually trying to do v7 and v6 is working but not what i need to do